# How do you run a single query through mysql from the command line?

Tags: sql, mysql, unix, command-line

I'm looking to be able to run a single query on a remote server in a scripted task.

For example, intuitively, I would imagine it would go something like:

```
mysql -uroot -p -hslavedb.mydomain.com mydb_production "select * from users;"
```

Answer (score 354, accepted):

```
mysql -u <user> -p -e 'select * from schema.table'
```

(Note the use of single quotes rather than double quotes, to avoid the shell expanding the * into filenames)

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql.exe -u root -p -e "my query"---->ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: This should be the first result in a google search (for "mysql exec sql from command line") and not the huge mysql site!

Comment: I don't know why but double quotes was not working for me, had to turn them into single quotes

Comment: Also, if you want to strip the header and table format you can use `mysql -u <user> -p -B --disable-column-names -e 'select * from schema.table'`

Comment: @tinybyte Assuming Linux: Insinde doublequotes the asterisk `*` gets expanded to all files in the current directory, while this expansion does not happen in singlequotes, thats the reason why. Doublequotes will work for quesries without the `*`.

Comment: This worked for me, except I'm new at this, and didn't realize if you want to pass the actual password you need to use -p1234 not -p 1234.  Very poor security practice I'm sure, but useful for dev.

Comment: @Dr.jacky I'm sure you don't really have the need any more, but for the future, if your root user has no password, dont pass -p option as blank, just dont pass it at all i.e. `mysql.exe -u root -e "my query"`

Comment: Great answer but the double quote thing is a clear concern, given that the question is tagged with Unix. I've submitted an edit to address that...

Comment: Can I avoid the `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at` because of - probably - js mode which is the default starting mode?

Comment: This just prints out the usage for me

Comment: @NobbZ But shouldn't `*` in string literals be always escaped for safety?

Answer (score 38):

```
mysql -uroot -p -hslavedb.mydomain.com mydb_production -e "select * from users;"
```

From the usage printout:

> `-e`, `--execute=name`
>   Execute command and quit. (Disables `--force` and history file)

Answer (score 22):

here's how you can do it with a cool shell trick:

```
mysql -uroot -p -hslavedb.mydomain.com mydb_production <<< 'select * from users'
```

'<<<' instructs the shell to take whatever follows it as stdin, similar to piping from echo.

use the -t flag to enable table-format output

Answer (score 16):

If it's a query you run often, you can store it in a file. Then any time you want to [run it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html):

```
mysql < thefile
```

(with all the login and database flags of course)

Answer (score 9):

```
echo "select * from users;" | mysql -uroot -p -hslavedb.mydomain.com mydb_production
```

Answer (score 1):

As by the time of the question containerization wasn't that popular, this is how you pass a single query to a dockerized database cluster with Ansible, following @RC.'s answer:

`ansible <host | group > -m shell -a "docker exec -it <container_name | container_id> mysql -u<your_user> -p<your_pass> <your_database> -e 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table;'"`

If not using Ansible, just login to the server and use `docker exec -it ...` part.

MySQL will issue a warning that passing credentials in plain text may be insecure, so be aware of your risks.

Answer (score 0):

From the `mysql` man page:

```
   You can execute SQL statements in a script file (batch file) like this:

       shell> mysql db_name < script.sql > output.tab
```

Put the query in `script.sql` and run it.