# How to find out the MySQL root password

Tags: mysql, database

I cannot figure out my MySQL root password; how can I find this out? Is there any file where this password is stored?

I am following this [link](http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=41793&page=1) but I do not have directadmin directory in local.

Comment: Found by a simple Google Search: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: default root password is - wait for it - "root" (without the quotes), or no password at all (and is that mysql server **really** yours)

Comment: yes it is my local mysql server on my laptop

Comment: so did somebody just pass through this question and dump a downvote on each _correct and relevant_ answer?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651898/resetting-root-password-in-mysql-5-6#32372318

Comment: [Mysql 5.7.24 get root first login](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236470/2153910)

Comment: If you're using PHPMyAdmin you may check the ...\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php file. It may save you some time digging or changing the password.
Obviously, all security-wise action advised.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows systems: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html

Answer (score 167):

thanks to @thusharaK I could reset the root password without knowing the old password.

On ubuntu I did the following:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking
```

Then run mysql in a new terminal:

```
mysql -u root
```

And run the following queries to change the password:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

*In MySQL 5.7, the password field in mysql.user table field was removed, now the field name is 'authentication_string'.*

Quit the mysql safe mode and start mysql service by:

```
mysqladmin shutdown
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: I had to use `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`
, with the new password.

Comment: Nice instruction flow especially: then run mysql in a new terminal

Comment: i can't do this `mysql -u root`. It shows error `Access denied`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Try this: sudo mysql -u root

Comment: Awesome. I am comprehending what worked in RHEL 7:

Terminal 1:
sudo service mysql stop

sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking

Terminal 2:
mysql -u root

UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new password') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
 
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown

Note: Once you shutdown mysqladmin, you would be seeing the safe mode exits in Terminal 1.

sudo service mysql start

That's it and it works like a charm with the new password!

Comment: For mysql 5.7.xx replace `Password` with `authentication_string`. The column `Password` has been removed as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692812/mysql-user-db-does-not-have-password-columns-installing-mysql-on-osx).

Comment: How to exit mysql safe mode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27755214/261405

Answer (score 79):

You can't view the hashed password; the only thing you can do is reset it!

Stop MySQL:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

or

```
$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

Start it in safe mode:

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

(above line is the whole command)

This will be an ongoing command until the process is finished so open another shell/terminal window, log in without a password:

```
$ mysql -u root

mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

MySQL 5.7 and over:

```
mysql> use mysql; 
mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('password') where user='root';
```

Exit the MySQL CLI:

```
mysql> exit
```

Restart MySQL in normal mode, first stopping the safe mode instance:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown   # (when prompted, enter the new password just set)
$ sudo service mysql start
```

or

```
$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Your new password is 'password'.

Comment: sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
sudo: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: command not found

Comment: What to do in this case?

Comment: Looks like mysql is not installed properly. Uninstall it properly and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Something went odd with my  `mysql_secure_installation` and root was no longer cooperating. What does the `authentication_string` setting do?

Comment: To restart, try `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown` with the new password then `sudo service mysql start`

Answer (score 68):

One thing that tripped me up on a new install of MySQL and wondering why I couldn't get the default password to work and why even the reset methods where not working.
Well turns out that on Ubuntu 18 the most recent version of MySQL server does not use password auth at all for the root user by default. So this means it doesn't matter what you set it to, it won't let you use it. It's expecting you to login from a privileged socket.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

This will not work, even if you are using the correct password.

Instead, you need to use:

```
sudo mysql
```

that will work with out any password.
then once you in you need type in

```
 ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Password you want to use';
```

Then log out and now it will accept your password.

Comment: That was the only one that worked with me! Thanks

Answer (score 47):

MySQL 5.7 and above saves root in MySQL log file.

Please try this:

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Comment: In my case the password was not here; however, instead, `/var/log/mysql/error.log` contained a warning about the root password being empty - so this kind of saved my day :)

Comment: On MySQL 8.0.27, this entry was from 4+ years ago and the password provided did not work. Perhaps this is a temporary password from first boot?

Answer (score 19):

You cannot find it. It is stored in a database, which you need the root password to access, and even if you did get access somehow, it is hashed with a one-way hash. You can reset it: [How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: This answer actually is a response to the question. Most others got by the implicit assumption what the probleme behind the answer (forgot root password) is and how to solve that.

Answer (score 18):

Follow these steps to reset password in Windows system

1. Stop Mysql service from task manager
2. Create a text file and paste the below statement

> MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier:
>
> `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yournewpassword');`

> MySQL 5.7.6 and later:
>
> `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yournewpassword';`

3. Save as `mysql-init.txt` and place it in `'C' drive`.
4. Open command prompt and paste the following

`C:\> mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt`

Comment: This was a life saver, GREAT tip!

Comment: worked in Centos7 `mysqld --init-file=/root/m.txt`. I added above command `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yournewpassword');` to */root/m.txt*

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

On terminal type the following

`$ sudo mysql -u root -p`

Enter password://*just press enter*

mysql>

Comment: it seems that mysql server is not using password auth by default anymore.  you have to start mysql client as a super user (sudo) to gain access until you change the login method.

Comment: This indicated `Access denied for user 'root'@localhost' (using password: NO)` for me.

Answer (score 8):

Unless the package manager requests you to type the root password during installation, the default root password is the empty string. To connect to freshly installed server, type:

```
shell> mysql -u root --password=
mysql>
```

To change the password, get back the unix shell and type:

```
shell> mysqladmin -u root --password= password root
```

The new password is 'root'. Now connect to the server:

```
shell> mysql -u root --password=
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Oops, the password has changed. Use the new one, `root`:

```
shell> mysql -u root --password=root
...
blah, blah, blah : mysql welcome banner
...
mysql>
```

Bingo! New do something interesting

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Maurycy

Comment: it's not using passwords but authenticated sockets by default now. so just changing the password isn't good enough anymore.

Answer (score 8):

As addition to the other answers, in a cpanel installation, the mysql root password is stored in a file named `/root/.my.cnf`. (and the cpanel service resets it back on change, so the other answers here won't help)

Answer (score 6):

you can view mysql root password , well i have tried it on mysql 5.5 so do not know about other new version well work or not

```
nano ~/.my.cnf
```

Answer (score 5):

The default password which worked for me after immediate installation of mysql server is : `mysql`

Comment: maybe he didn't answer the question, but many people coming here may find it solve thier problem.

Answer (score 3):

The procedure changes depending the version of MySql. Follow the procedure exactly as described for your version:

- HINTS - Read before the instructions page for your version of MySql*
- In step 5: Instead of run CMD, create a shortcut on your desktop calling CDM.exe. Then right-click on the shortcut and select "Execute as Administrator".
- In step 6: Skip the first proposed version of the command and execute the second one, the one with the --defaults-file parameter
- Once you execute the command, if everything is ok, the CMD window remains open and the command of step 6 continues executing. Simply close the window (click 'x'), and then force close MySQl from the Task Manager.
- Delete the file with the SQL commands, and start again MySQL. The password must be changed now.

5.0
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

5.1
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html

... just change the version in the link (5.5, 5.6, 5.7)

Answer (score 3):

In your "hostname".err file inside the data folder MySQL works on, try to look for a string that starts with:

"A temporary password is generated for roor@localhost "

you can use

```
less /mysql/data/dir/hostname.err
```

then slash command  followed by the string you wish to look for

```
/"A temporary password"
```

Then press n, to go to the Next result.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this a different way, this may be easier for some.

I did it this way because I tried starting in safe mode but cannot connect with the error:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

What I did was to connect normally as root:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
```

Then I created a new super user:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'myuser'@'%' identified by 'mypassword' with grant option;
mysql> quit
```

Then log in as myuser

```
$ mysql -u myuser -p -h localhost
```

Trying to change the password gave me no errors but did nothing for me so I dropped and re-created the root user

```
mysql> drop user 'root'@'localhost;
mysql> mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'mypassword' with grant option;
```

The root user is now working with the new password

Answer (score 2):

Using Debian / Ubuntu mysql packages, you can login with user `debian-sys-maint`, which has all the expected privileges, the password is stored in the file `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`

Answer (score 1):

Answers provided here did not seem to work for me, the trick turned out to be:
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';`

(complete answer here: [Change user password in MySQL 5.7 with “plugin: auth_socket”](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/))

Answer (score 0):

**System:**

- CentOS Linux 7
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25

**Procedure:**

1. Open two shell sessions, logging in to one as the Linux root user
   and the other as a nonroot user with access to the `mysql` command.
2. In your root session, stop the normal mysqld listener and start a
   listener which bypasses password authentication (*note: this is a
   significant security risk* as anyone with access to the `mysql` 
   command may access your databases without a password.  You may want 
   to close active shell sessions and/or disable shell access before 
   doing this):

   `# systemctl stop mysqld`
   `# /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables -u mysql &`
3. In your nonroot session, log in to mysql and set the mysql root password:

   `$ mysql`
   `mysql> flush privileges;`
   `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

   `mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');`
   `Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)`

   `mysql> quit;`
4. In your root session, kill the passwordless instance of mysqld and restore the normal mysqld listener to service:

   `# kill %1`
   `# systemctl start mysqld`
5. In your nonroot session, test the new root password you configured above:

   `$ mysql -u root -p`
   `Enter password:`
   `Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.`
   `...`
   `mysql>`

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this problem for a couple of minutes and the following was the only solution that actually worked:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/access-denied-for-user-root-localhost

1. `sudo mysql`
2. `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'insert_password';`
3. `mysql -u root -p`

Answer (score 0):

In case you already set a password in the past the `mysql -uroot -p` solution *will not work*,

In my case I used some of the answers above to solve this (Ubuntu 16). The result was:

```sh
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

if you see this text in the screen:
***mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.***
then do:

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld

sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & # Look at the & at the end!
```

**Enter other terminal** to set your password like this:

```sh
sudo mysql -u root

mysql> use mysql;
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost'=PASSWORD('__NEW__PASSWORD__');
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit;
```

then restart the service and login

```sh
# end mysqld_safe in the other terminal
sudo service mysql start
sudo mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 5.5 on Windows 10

You can't find the password as it is hashed in the table, so resetting it is the only option.

The solution of importing the new password script by .txt file, as offered by Lokesh kumar Chippada, didn't work for me. I found that the command prompt just froze after initiating the import.

I added `skip-grant-tables` to the my.ini file as per the top the answer on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables) by tonycoupland.

I was then able to login to mysql from the command line

`$> mysql`

and then in mysql

`mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

`mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');`

See 'B.3.3.2.3 Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions' on [mysql dev page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html). I have now removed `skip-grant-tables` from the my.ini file, and I can login as a root user using the new password I created.

Answer (score -7):

Go to phpMyAdmin > config.inc.php > $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

Comment: There's nothing in the question about `phpmyadmin`.