# Resetting ROOT password in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, windows-7, passwords, password-recovery, mysql-5.6

I have been following [these instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html) for resetting **root** password for local installation of `MySQL 5.6` on Windows 7 laptop.

I stopped the service, created *init-file*, and ran the following command (as Administrator):

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" --init-file=C:\\MySQL-misc\\mysql-init.txt
```

I got the following **warning**:

> 2014-02-08 15:44:10 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value
>   is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server
>   option (see documentation for more details).

Since it's a warning I'm not sure whether I need to fix anything and then redo the process again.

Currently the command window is still on and does not accept any input. Should I force-close it or is there anything I can do to complete the process gracefully?

**UPDATE**

I killed the Command window and tried to restart the service.  Got an error.

Restarted Windows and the service automatically started. The **new** `root password` seems to work.  I was successfully able to use various functions of Workbench that require the password.

So, the warning was indeed just a warning.

Comment: @Mr.Radica - I posted it as an **UPDATE**.  I think it *might* help someone else, so I didn't delete it.

Comment: Good job. You could still place it below and then accept it. You did solve your initial problem. ;-)

Comment: I tried almost an hour, followed the instructions on MySQL manual with no success, flushing priviledges etc.. After restarting the computer it worked.

Comment: Thanks! For mysql 5.7, you need to use authentication_string

Comment: https://youtu.be/gFo5DV_pSg8 - This video helped me in changing password in one of my production servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been **resolved**.

As stated in my question I followed  [instructions from MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html).

The process did not go *exactly* as described (and this was the reason for my original post) but it worked nevertheless (see **UPDATE** section in my post).

Comment: thanks alot.... strange ... for me other answers not worked but this answer worked like steph curry 3 points ;)

Answer (score 63):

**On Windows**:

0) shut down service `mysql56`

1) go to `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6`, note that `ProgramData` is a hidden folder

2) looking for file `my.ini`, open it and add one line `skip-grant-tables` below `[mysqld]`,save

```
[mysqld]

skip-grant-tables
```

3) start service `mysql56`

4) by right, you can access the database, run `mysql`

5) and use the query below to update the password

```
update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('NEW PASSWORD') where user='root';
```

**note**: for newer version, use `authentication_string` instead of `password`

6) shut down the service again, remove the line `skip-grant-tables` save it, and start the service again. try to use the password you set to login.

---

**On Mac**:

0) stop the service

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

1) skip grant table

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

once it's running, don't close it, and open a new terminal window

2) go into mysql terminal

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

3) update the password

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

for newer version like 5.7, use

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

4) run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

5) run `\q` to quit

6) start the mysql server

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Comment: downvoted because you don't actually say where or how to connect to run the update statement. be complete in your answer.

Comment: you forgot FLUSH PRIVILEGES in the 1st (nonMac) instructions? other than that, this worked great, better than the instructions on the MySQL manual

Comment: Should be noted that there is no 'password' column, at least not in MySql 5.7.  Use 'authentication_string', as in @SatishakumarAwati's answer.

Comment: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'`

Comment: @CsabaToth Try `authentication_string`

Comment: @Timeless That worked. But you only have that under the Mac. I have Linux & Win

Comment: On macOS with MySQL 5.6.42 I had to use the `UPDATE` statement indicated for MySQL 5.7.

Comment: where does this line get inputted? 
"update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('NEW PASSWORD') where user='root';"

Answer (score 6):

- Stop Mysql service by going into Administrative tools > Services
- Open Start > Run > cmd (**Run as administrator**)
- Start the server manually using this line:

  ```
  mysqld -P3306 --skip-grant-tables
  ```
- In new cmd (**Run as administrator**) execute :

  ```
  mysql -P3306 mysql
  ```
- Execute the following query in mysql client:

  ```
  update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('new_password') where user='root';
  ```

That's it!!

Answer (score 2):

Updating [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32372318/4279419) regarding to changes at MySQL 5.7:

0) shut down service `mysql57`

1) go to `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7`, note that `ProgramData` is a hidden folder

2) looking for file `my.ini`, open it and add one line `skip-grant-tables` below `[mysqld]`,save

```
[mysqld]

skip-grant-tables
```

3) start service `mysql57`

4) by right, you can access the database, run mysql

5) and use the query below to update the password

`update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('NEW_PASSWORD') where user='root';`

6) shut down the service again, remove the line `skip-grant-tables` save it, and start the service again. try to use the password you set to login.

Answer (score 1):

#### First stop mysql server and follow below steps:

Go to mysql bin directory on cmd i,e. `cd C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin` (Its a hidden directory)

#### skip grant tables will allow you enter into mysql

- `mysqld.exe --skip-grant-tables`

#### Open new command prompt or on same command prompt

- `mysql.exe -uroot -p` (without any password you can login to mysql)

#### run below query to change mysql root password

- `UPDATE mysql.user set password=password('root password') WHERE user='root';`
- `flush privileges`

#### Thats it, Restart mysql and good to go with new  password..!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error: `mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.` when attempting to reset your root password. You might try:

```sh
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & 
mysql -uroot
update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('your_password') where user='root';
flush privileges;
quit
sudo killall mysql
sudo service mysql start
mysql -u root -pyour_password
```

> Tested in MySQL 5.7 running in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have Xampp installed.

1. Goto C:\xampp\mysql\bin
2. Open my.ini file
3. Put `skip-grant-tables` under `[mysqld]`
4. Goto windows services and stop mysql service
5. Trigger this command from command prompt `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql`
6. Now, reset the root password with the MySQL query `update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('root') where user='root';`
7. Exit the command prompt.
8. Restart the mysql windows service that was turned off in step 4.
9. Now you will be able to login to mysql using password as root.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 5.6 on Windows I had to run this statement to make it work.

```
UPDATE mysql.user
SET Password=PASSWORD('NEW PASSWORD'), 
authentication_String=PASSWORD('NEW PASSWORD')
WHERE User='root';
```

Comment: Where do you run this statement? in cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Without editing mi.ini:

```
service mysql stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

on a separate ssh session:

```
update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('NEW PASSWORD') where user='root';
```

no need to flush privileges, just restart the server