# Resetting MySQL Passwrod

Tags: mysql, passwords, reset

Attempting to reset MySQL password.  I have read all of the other threads and even the MySQL site for windows OS instructions (stop service, create init file with password change statements, start service) but I still receive the "access denied for user 'root@localhost'" message.  Could there be any newer instructions for this process as I did notice that some of the inline parameters have been depricated, but they only give warnings.

After a lot of trial and a lot more error, I still am not able to get the password changed.  Providing a bit more information in hopes I can get some help:

**mysql-init.txt contains the following**
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('kevin');

**command line is as follows:**
mysqld -nt --init-file=c:\mysql-init.txt

I am running as admin or elevated for all processes.

Comment: Did you actually **run** the init file as **Administator**?  [It worked for me.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651898/resetting-root-password-in-mysql-5-6)

Comment: Yes.  I ran as administrator and elevated when necessary when executing the command line instructions.

Comment: In the link it says "restarted windows".  Did you have to do a reboot?  I had not seen that in any of the other instructions.

Comment: Yes, I did. It was my way to make sure that the service starts automatically.

Comment: I will give that a try and see what happens.

Comment: Good luck.  Try Workbench afterwards.

Comment: That didn't seem to work but I tried the mySQLd command afterward and and the cursor has not come back.  It's been about 10 minutes.  I read that you had a similar issue.  How long before it returned?

Comment: It didn't. I had to kill the window.

Comment: Still no luck.  Updated my original question with some more information in hopes of getting some more direction.