# Is MySQL root password too complex on installation on windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, installation

Upon installing MySQL from Oracle on my Windows machine I was prompted to enter a root password for the MySQL server. I set the following password:

eL;(4QWe-nIhq'A%t@cpJN{7PaVwvcTcsdGAYx8K

Now when I try to change settings on this server the installer asks me for my root password. When I try to type this I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception has occured in your application. If you click
>   Continue, the application will ignore this error an attempt to
>   continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>
> Keyword not supported.
>
> Parameter Name: (4QWe-nIhq'A%t@cpJN{7PaVwvcTcsdGAYx8K; protocol.

[image: Error Upon Typing the Password]

Is the solution just to work with a simpler password?

Comment: The problem seems to be related to using a "(" in the password which seems to be not allowed.

Comment: It appears the installer doesn't properly escape the password, interpreting the `'` as end-of-string character. Frankly, quite ridiculous. As for how to change the password: through the command line, try searching.

Comment: So, they have SQL injection in installers! Cool!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resetting ROOT password in MySQL 5.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651898/resetting-root-password-in-mysql-5-6)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by reinstalling the server. Another method to resetting the password is as follows:
[documenation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

1. Log on to your system as Administrator.
2. Stop the MySQL server if it is running. For a server that is running as a Windows service, go to the Services manager: From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL service in the list and stop it.
   If your server is not running as a service, you may need to use the Task Manager to force it to stop.
3. Create a text file containing the password-assignment statement on a single line. Replace the password with the password that you want to use.

MySQL 5.7.6 and later:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

Save the file. The example assumes that you name the file C:\mysql-init.txt.

4. Open a console window to get to the command prompt: From the Start menu, select Run, then enter cmd as the command to be run.

Start the MySQL server with the special --init-file option (notice that the backslash in the option value is doubled):

```
C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"
C:\> mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```