# MySQL; Create a secondary root user without having the current root user's password

Tags: mysql

I know this will sound weird and contrived, but this is the scenario:

I was handed an application that runs on Windows and it uses a MySQL DB. I need to create an API to do a few queries on the DB and extract some data, but I don't have the root user's password.

Now, it'd be all fine and dandy if I could actually change the root user's password. The thing is that the genius that developed the application hard-coded the root password in it.

So, to sum it up, I'm looking for ideas on creating another root-level user on that MySQL instance without knowing the root user password (I'm thinking it may be done with an init script the same way resetting the password is done, maybe? - remember this is Windows). Oh, this is MySQL 5.0.95, by the way.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Does this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651898/resetting-root-password-in-mysql-5-6?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Shutdown your mysql instance and reset it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6085495/43959

Comment: An application that connects using the root database credentials to server software that has had no security patches for four years.  Seems legit.  So, you're saying the root password is hard coded... compiled into... in the application... and also nobody knows what it is?

Comment: That's right, Michael... looks like I'm screwed.