# Netbeans MySQL connection : Server properties error

Tags: mysql, netbeans, phpmyadmin, lamp, ubuntu-19.04

I am working on `Netbeans-11.0` with `JDK12` on `Ubuntu 19.04`.
I have `LAMP server` with which I use phpMyAdmin to connect to MySQL server.
Now I am trying to connect Netbeans to MySQL server but it shows an error.
Please help me..

Error message : ***null, message from server: "Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL sever"***
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha5BS.png)

Comment: Interesting perhaps update the permissions to connect from any host (%)

Comment: Before you allow any host, try first if your local IP works (you can find it when you run the command ifconfig inside a terminal).

Comment: Please update your question to provide the exact error you are getting in text form. The crucial error message in the screen shot is almost illegible, and is also not searchable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Host '::1' or '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871109/mysql-host-1-or-127-0-0-1-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)