# Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server using node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-modules

i am using Mac Machine. and using Bitnami MAMP stack 7.2 for create Database in MYSQL ,
here is link for that Mysql database access :
`http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?server=1&db=liodb`

its working fine , my requirement is  connect this local database to my node application here is my connection code in node js

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: '3306',
    user: "lio_user",
    password: "lio123456",
    database:  'liodb'
   });
```

but i am not able to connect getting error

```
  code: 'ER_HOST_NOT_PRIVILEGED',
  errno: 1130,
  sqlMessage: "Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this 
  MySQL server",
  sqlState: undefined,
  fatal: true
```

Comment: but mysql port is `3306`

Comment: Yes and i am using same

Comment: now i got the solution : we should add adapter: 'sails-mysql',
socketPath : '/Applications/mampstack-7.2.22-0/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' in our connection code in js

Comment: I was also looking for such an error and found a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67574175