# Unable to create password or login as root user after installing mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

After installing with `brew install mysql` I run 'brew services run mysql' and get a response indicating that the server is successfully running. Whether next I try to login with

`mysql -u root -p`

and enter a password (or blank) OR if I use `mysql_secure_installation` to SET a password and try again, I always get this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times and tried again. I have tried installing via .dmg directly from the site as well. In this case I am prompted to create a password on installation. I get the same above error when I try to log in to mysql via the terminal.

Further when I attempt to connect via MySQLWorkbench I get the following error.

`Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306:Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found`

Comment: See if any answers to [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651898/resetting-root-password-in-mysql-5-6) help.

Comment: Try Workbench 8, which can cope with the new authentication pluigin (currently RC, soon there will be a GA version).