# How do I exit MySQL safe mode?

Tags: mysql

I stupidly tried MySQL_update as I am having issues granting permissions to remote ips but I went into safe mode with /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

and now I can't get out of it

[image]

How do I get out of this safemode

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, your last command didn't end, so type `;` to end the current command. Then you can continue, including the following to exit mysql altogether.

Simply use the following command/keys.

Hold CTRL and press X or Z

Comment: They are in mysqld, not mysql; there is no current command; CTRL+Z by itself will only push to background (but not stop). Correct answer is from vczm to use mysqladmin in another terminal (or use CTRL+Z to put into background, then use mysqladmin).

Answer (score 14):

CTRL + Z will suspend `mysqld_safe` process, which can be revival by `fg` command. For killing the `mysqld_safe` you need to run `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown` in another terminal or after hold CTRL + Z

Comment: Correct answer is this one.

Comment: The server will fail to return to work normally and errors such as "```Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.```", will appear,
 so this "```mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown```" command is very appropriate.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Activity monitor ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhM9D.png)
For those who are on MAC, go to activity monitor, Under 'CPU' tab, search for 'mysqld' process and Terminate.

I'd assume the same for Windows in Task Manager