# Unable to batch in data to mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to batch in data to mysql using the

`mysql < schema.sql -u root -p`

I'm then prompted for the root password.  After submitting the password, I get

`Please use --connect-expired-password option or invoke mysql in interactive mode.`

I'm not sure how to get past this requirement, or even why mysql is asking this of me.  I'm able to use this command to batch in data to mysql on another machine without any other requirements.  The failing machine is running mysql 5.7.9; the successful machine is using version 5.6.26.

Comment: So maybe try use: --connect-expired-password

Comment: When I try to use --connect-expired-password, I get      ERROR 1820 (HY000) at line 1: You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.    I'm unclear on why my current settings don't allow me to run this operation

Comment: So now you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467337/reset-mysql-root-password-using-alter-user-statement-after-install-on-mac

Answer (score 4):

mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_new_password');