# Mysql reset password error

Tags: mysql

I had mysql already installed in my system and I uninstalled it because it was not running successfully.
Now when I installed a new version of mysql, the server starts and stops successfully. But it still accepts the password of my old mysql.
If I try to change the password, which I need to because it says my old password has expired when I try to connect it to workbench, it gives me the following error:

`File './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)`

I also tried running this command:

```
 mysql -uroot -p
```

It accepts my old password and then if I further run any other command, example

```
mysql> USE mysql;
```

It asks me to reset the password and when I do it again gives me the above error

Comment: Do the answers from this previous question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467337/reset-mysql-root-password-using-alter-user-statement-after-install-on-mac

Comment: yes I tried this, it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've trashed your MySQL system tables you'll need to recreate them with the [`mysql_install_db`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-install-db.html) command-line tool or something equivalent. This is done while the server process is stopped and should initialize everything correctly.

Comment: I tried ```mysqld --initialize```. It says: ```[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.```

Comment: You might need to manually purge any left-over bits from your previous install.

Comment: I removed all the left overs and reinstalled mysql and it works :D There was some file which had not been deleted