# Reset password mysql

Tags: mysql, passwords

I am struggling with the reset of the password on mysql.
I am using the version 5.7 and I am working on windows 8.
I have looking for solutions on this forum, but I am still blocked.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7>mysql -u root
mysql> UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('M@ngo') WHERE user='root';
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
mysql> USE mysql;
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must SET PASSWORD before executing this statement.
```

So I am looping without solutions ...
Thank you for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset MySQL root password using ALTER USER statement after install on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467337/reset-mysql-root-password-using-alter-user-statement-after-install-on-mac)

Comment: I found this query ---UPDATE mysql.user
    SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;';--- reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html