# MySQL error: You must reset your password

Tags: mysql

I have changed the password using the following statement:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password' PASSWORD EXPIRE;
```

Nevertheless, I still receive the following error:

> ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.

MySQL version is 8.0.11

Comment: duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467337/reset-mysql-root-password-using-alter-user-statement-after-install-on-mac

Answer (score 4):

Copied the below answer from this: [Reset MySQL root password using ALTER USER statement after install on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467337/reset-mysql-root-password-using-alter-user-statement-after-install-on-mac)

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('your_new_password')
       WHERE User='root';
```

> ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER
>   statement before executing this statement.

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_new_password');
```

> Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

This is where I found the answer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-user.html