# Can not log in with root user to mysql in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-18.04

Well, there is always surprise with newer versions of software. This time they are Ubuntu 18.04 and Mysql. I followed every step https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04. Now `sudo mysql -u root -p` gives access denied error. Can't log in to phpmyadmin too. Cheers!!! Spend hours to solve but nothing.
--------------------------------------/

I got my fault. Tutorial says to run `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`. It looks like `password` is auth method, but it turns out it is password itself, that is, after `mysql -u root -p` you need enter `password`

Comment: Have you tried without creds? : `$ sudo mysql` or `$ mysql`

Comment: yes, same error, because I switched to password methods from mega secure auth_socket method

Comment: Might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467337/reset-mysql-root-password-using-alter-user-statement-after-install-on-mac