# How to execute mysql query with password in ansible playbook

Tags: mysql, linux, ansible

Ansible playbook:

**Case 1**

```
- name: case 1
  command: mysql -u root -p "MyNewPass_123" --execute="show databases;"
```

Result:

```
 "stdout_lines": ["Please use --connect-expired-password option or invoke mysql in interactive mode."]
```

If I add "--connect-expired-password" to the command, I get the following error

```
ERROR 1820 (HY000) at line 1: You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement."
```

**Case 2**

```
- name: case 2
  command: mysql -u root -p --execute="show databases;"
```

Result:
Playbook wait enter password.

How can I do it?

Comment: It seems your password expired. Ansible can't do much about it. Fix it in MySQL.

Comment: As Vladimir pointed, this doesn't have much to do with ansible, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467337/reset-mysql-root-password-using-alter-user-statement-after-install-on-mac

Comment: but i can to connection using only linux terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install the galaxy collection:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install community.mysql
```

After you can use the module `community.mysql.mysql_query`:

```
- name: Select query to db acme with positional arguments
  community.mysql.mysql_query:
    login_user: root
    login_password: MyNewPass_123
    login_db: ${DB_TO_USE}
    query: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = %s AND param = %s
    positional_args:
    - 1
    - test
```

For further info refer to:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_query_module.html