Use @ literal in SQL command text
I want to change a password for a user in MySQL which requires @ symbol. However, C# SQL command uses that as a parameter holder and because of that the following command fails.
command.CommandText = $"ALTER USER '{user}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{password}'";
How does one escape or force DbCommand to use literal @?
I am aware of SQL injection issues. I am going this in a console app as one time maintenance to do some data migration.

Inside a SQL string it should just be treated as a normal @

@flackoverstow Unfortunately, it is not. It tries to use it as a parameter placeholder and the SQL command fails. MySQL complains: Parameter '@'%'' must be defined.

mySQL doesn't use SqlCommand. One uses MySqlCommand. See here.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467337/reset-mysql-root-password-using-alter-user-statement-after-install-on-mac

@marsze if the username doesn't have special characters, single quotes are not needed by I tried with them also and the result in the same.

@user246821 I am using MySqlCommand actually but this can be generalized to DbCommand in general regardless of the database provider. The problem still persists. The SO link you pasted in not useful as it also requires the use of @ in the SQL command text which was the problem is in the first place.

@Mensur: It's my understanding that SO is for specific questions, not generalized ones.

@Mensur: According to the mySQL documentation: The @'host_name' part is optional. An account name consisting only of a user name is equivalent to 'user_name'@'%'.

Are you using the MySqlConnector NuGet package? Which version?

The MySQL connector tries to parse SQL to implement named parameters, and seemingly offers no way to escape @; accounts and roles are the one syntax affected by it. Luckily, you’re using @'%', and @'%' is the default.
command.CommandText = $"ALTER USER '{user}' IDENTIFIED BY '{password}'";

You might even be able to use parameters. If this works, you should – one-off or not, it’s just much cleaner.
command.CommandText = "ALTER USER @User IDENTIFIED BY @Password";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", user);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);


I tried this exact syntax with MySqlConnector 2.3.7 and didn't get any exceptions. I also added a test that should fail if this was a problem, but didn't detect any issues: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/commit/9efc679afa3d662fef2684adc89fe4152e272817. Any ideas on how to reproduce the claimed problem?

@BradleyGrainger: No, unfortunately I tried to answer this by code inspection and trusting the asker only. Not sure what I missed in the parser; will check properly when I get the chance.

I am using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql version 6.0.2

Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 6.0.2 uses MySqlConnector 2.1.2; I also tested with that version and didn't experience any problems. Pomelo does automatically set some additional connection string options like AllowUserVariables=true; (https://github.com/search?q=repo%3APomeloFoundation%2FPomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql%20AllowUserVariables&type=code) but that didn't make a difference in my testing.

@Ry- I think you're right that it seems like it should be broken for this kind of input. I might need to debug it and find out what's going on; that might provide a clue for how to repro.

Oh, it turns out the OP wasn't actually running the code in the question, but was actually using $"ALTER USER {user}@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{password}'". That does cause an issue.

@BradleyGrainger: Looks like SingleQuotedStringSingleQuote can only transition back to Beginning or Statement while still consuming a character. Seems like that might be an issue for 'foo'/*bar … without a space?

Opened an issue to track this: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/1480.

This bug (?) seems to have been solved when using MySqlConnector 2.4.0.

It turns out that adding single quotes around the username solves the problem. For example: command.CommandText = $"ALTER USER '{usr}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{pwd}'" works resulting in SQL command text of ALTER USER 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd123'. However, username does not have to be quoted if it does not have special characters. For example, the following SQL works fine when executed through MySQL client from command line: ALTER USER user1@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd123' but the same SQL fails when executed through MySqlCommand resulting in error: Parameter '@'%'' must be defined.
Edit: Adding AllowUserVariables=true to the connection string as @Bradley Grainger pointed out also works.

You didn't quote the full exception message. It reads: Parameter '@'%'' must be defined. To use this as a variable, set 'Allow User Variables=true' in the connection string. You can solve this issue by adding AllowUserVariables=true; to your connection string.
