# Changing MySQL root password doesn't reflect in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I changed the root password for MySQL as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26233939/6400614) answer.

But my understanding is that this would change the root password when accessing the same MySQL from PHP.

Earlier the root password was an empty string (`""`) in PHP MySQL, as in doing this would work:

  `$dbConn = new mysqli("localhost","root","");`

But even after changing the root password as in the answer above, it doesn't reflect in PHP MySQL.

As in, if I changed the `root` password to `X`.Then while using `mysqli_connect()` method, if I do:

  `$dbConn = new mysqli("localhost","root","X");`

It says `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`
BUT, if I continue the old way, it suceeds.

Am I missing something here? Is there something wrong that I have done?

I can provide any extra details if needed.

Comment: When you say does not reflect can you clarify ?

Comment: I have added necessary explanations, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have phpmyadmin??

Comment: Yes, I have phpmyadmin and I am able to access it. Although the `user` table inside `mysql` database has the password field named as `password` whereas the same field was named as `authentication_string` when I was changing the root password.

Comment: I know it's a silly question, but are you 100% definitely accessing the same server in both cases?

Comment: And, otherwise, are you using any sort of cached/pooled setup that might prevent the change from being picked up? I would try restarting the MySQL server, unless it's being used for anything else of course.

Comment: Okay, I'll see what's causing the problem. Even I'm not sure that it's running the same server on both sides. I'll try uninstalling MySQL and XAMPP and then verify.