# Not able to login to mySql from terminal

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, terminal

I read and followed the process on https://websiteforstudents.com/install-mysql-8-0-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/ to install mySql on my ubuntu virtual machine.
Everyhting run just absolutely fine. But when i try to

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

on the terminal it gives error like

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I am not able to even reset my password as nothing is opening. Is there any way to reset password (if that's the problem) from the terminal.

**UPDATE**

I read on [How to find out the MySQL root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895163/how-to-find-out-the-mysql-root-password) the way but after the first

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

when i try to

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

It gives me error like

```
2018-06-27T06:24:15.801227Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2018-06-27T06:24:15.802880Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

I repeated the whole download process still the error seems to persist. Moreover though i am the admin using

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
```

tells me that i dont have the permission to do the creation

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
```

Comment: It seems the password that you entering need to be verified.

Comment: How do i verify my password?

Comment: While configuring you entered the password the same password you need to entered. Might be you missing the case, else you have to go for  different approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the step that will help you to reset the password for root user.

Here I am using "mysqld", in your system you might need to use "mysql"

## Stop the Mysql Service and start in safe mode

```
service mysqld stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

## If above mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables gives error then:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

## Connect to mysql without password

```
mysql
```

## Now reset the root password and exit

## One of below will work for your mysql: (either with password or authentication_string column)

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD('NEW-PASSWORD') WHERE User='root';
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('NEW-PASSWORD') WHERE User='root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

## Shutdown the mysql safe mode service

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

## Start the mysql service normally

```
service mysqld start
```

## Now login with new password to mysql with new password.

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Comment: If it gives the error while starting in safe mode, you need to create the directory and give the permission as :    sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the MySQL root user. Try logging in as root on the linux maschine an login from there to the mysql as root:

```
sudo su # or just su, if you don't have sudo
mysql # normally, no further parameter are needed. If this is not working try mysql -u root
```

Comment: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) Gives this error  @mscho

Comment: Then most probably mysql is not started. Try `sudo service mysql start`. If is is still not starting, check the error logs.