# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have been used following command but it was not working.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ROOT@LOCALHOST IDENTIFIED BY "my_password";
```

Comment: possible useful if you are locked out of your database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables

Answer (score 1):

You are not connected (in the way of a login & username) to the database, you need to connect. depending on the way you acces the database.
in command line, you can use this:

```
mysql -pYourpassword -u username
```

Comment: now Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES

Comment: probably wrong password, have you been able to connect to your db in the past?

Comment: yes! i was granting and revoking privileges last day when got problem even i reset password as well as i searched lot on net.

Comment: Thats the hard way and will let you make a new password, if this is not a production base, then it could easily solve the problem. Let us know