# How can I restore the MySQL root user’s full privileges

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, reset

I accidentally removed all the privileges from my MySQL root user,

Is there some way I can restore this user to its original state (with all privileges)?

i m using my sql work bench 6.0

please let me know soultion step by step as i m new in my sql.

Comment: This question is off-topic and belongs on [dba.se]

Answer (score 7):

First try

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

if that does not work then do the following

1. Stop `mysqld` service with this ( on UNix-like systems)

   `sudo mysqld stop`
2. Restart it with the `--skip-grant-tables` option.
3. Connect to the mysql with just: `mysql` (i.e. no -p option, and username may not be required).
4. Use the following in the mysql client:

   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';`
5. Flush the privileges by running

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
6. Remove `--skip-grant-tables` option. and restart mysqld
7. Finally run

   `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`

Comment: I am using window, do I need to run all these commands in work bench6.0 or command prompt

Comment: if you are using windows see this on how to start mysqld with skip grant table option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables.. for the rest yes via command line is best

Comment: hi, I ahve followed the following prcess and still getting the same issue when i run the query.

Comment: hi, I have followed the following process http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables   and still getting the same issue when i run the query. "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';" error: UPDATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user'

Comment: hey forgot to add you need to remove --skip-grant-tables option before granting.

Comment: still it is showing the same error, I go to go to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.default as i did not found 'my.ini', I add the [mysqld]
skip-grant-tables then login to my sql and run the command "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';" it is showing the error "23:41:13 GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 0.000 sec
" Plesae let me know how I can solve this issue.