# mysql acces denied for creating database

Tags: mysql

I want to create new DB in mysql.

I am logged in as root. I have set password for root user.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR root;

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| Grants for root@%                                                                           |

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH GRANT OPTION |

| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION                                        
|

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database xxx;

ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'xxx'
```

One thing I notice that i do not have mysql db

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| info_schema        |
| sms_auto           |
| smstest            |
+--------------------+
```

Please can you help me

Comment: explicitly grant root@localhost, not root@wildcard

Comment: I tried this mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \*.\* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Ah wait, so you're trying to give yourself an upgrade in privileges.

Comment: Yes, I am logged in as root user and trying to create a database. but replied with access denied.

Comment: I think this is what you need to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714869/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-root-with-all-privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have started MySQL in safe mode then assigned appropriate privileges( Referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges))

1. Stop MySQL service
2. Run mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
3. Type MySQL -u root -p and press enter.
4. Enter your password
5. At the MySQL command line enter: use mysql;

After this, I have updated the privileges in mysql.user table for appropriate host and user. Flush privileges;

Now this works for me
you can also refer the answer for [update privilages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027487/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set your user privileges right
Like -host localhost -user root and -pass {your pass word}

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD;`. Set a user privilege to a particular user like people and then follow the example grant all on people.*to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'PASSWORD';

Comment: I have used GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: Try grant all on people.* to 'cgp'@'localhost' identified by 'myPass';

Comment: check this similar question https://serverfault.com/questions/669668/granting-database-permissions-in-mysql

Comment: I do not have mysql db and tried to check users table in all databases on server but does not have user table .

Comment: Were are you connecting? localhost or webserver?