# Can I disable mysql protection allowing access without any authentication in phpmyadmin (XAMPP)?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I tried to run my application on my localhost, but I am stuck with some problem.

Someone told me that I would need to give password for Users and Privileges. As a result, I have tried giving all permissions to users in Users and Privileges. But I don't know the username and password clearly (due to some problem).

Can I disable MySQL protection allowing access without any authentication in `phpmyadmin` (XAMPP)?

This is my error (during execution at localhost):

> CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Don't mind about my English :)

Comment: No offense, but the answer to this can be found by some Googling. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables

Comment: i didn't get anything clearly from that @RobMullins

Comment: My doubt is, can i disable mysql(phpmyadmin) without any authentication like password. @RobMullins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, authentication is not done at the phpMyAdmin level but at the MySQL level. To disable MySQL server's "protection" (authentication) you have to restart the MySQL server with a special option. So you have to find, depending on the XAMPP version, where the my.ini file is located, then edit it as described in [How to start MySQL with --skip-grant-tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables) (in the answer by tonycoupland) and restart the MySQL service.