# MySQL 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ' '@'localhost' to database 'mysql' with Mac

Tags: mysql

I ran MySQL with the Terminal with the following command.

```
mysql -u root
```

Then I tried to execute `use mysql;`, but it did not go properly but showed an unexpected message as follows.

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

Why do you think it's happening? Someone please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Your login credentials are wrong. Did you create a password while installing MySQL?

try `mysql -u root -p` and enter the password in the prompt to log in.

If you've lost your password, try resetting it. [View this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied) to reset password.

Comment: Now I get error 1045. Can you tell me the next step?

Comment: Did you try entering your password?

Comment: Reset your password and try.

Comment: @RicoAngeloni: If you find the answer useful, can you please upvote and mark as accepted answer?

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to reset the password.. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @RicoAngeloni: check out these links [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables] , [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html]