# MariaDB: both 'root' and '' without privileges (access denied 1044 & 1227)

Tags: mysql, macos, mariadb

I'm trying to do some queries, but I don't have any privilege whatsoever.
I can't understand why - it seemed to be working fine just a few weeks ago.

When I log in as 'root' with superuser (`sudo mysql -u root -p`) I still don't have any privileges and get error `1227` while trying to create an "`admin`" user.

When I login normally I end up with an anonymous user `''@'localhost'`, and don't have any privileges also.

I only have the Information_Schema database (and test), and using Sequel Pro I can see the `USER_PRIVILEGES` table, with only the anonymous user and with `USAGE` privileges only.

I'm basically stuck I can't do anything with my databases.
I've read thousands of posts, but just can't seem to find an answer.

Tried the `SELECT USER();` and then `GRANT ALL *.*` but I also get access denied.

Basically, I've been getting error 1044 and 1227 constantly.

Any idea on how to make a admin user with all privileges possible?
MariaDB is installed on my personal computer (MacOSX), so I would like to have all possible accesses.

Thanks a lot

EDIT: When stopping server with `mysql.server stop` and  trying to skip tables with: `mysqld --skip-grant-tables` I go into an infinite loop of:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
[Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files
```

Comment: Apparently fixed by reinstalling using brew. See t[his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522777/mariadb-both-root-and-without-privileges-access-denied-1044-1227#comment82003007_47523027).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stopping mariadb then starting with option to skip the grant tables; see:

[How to start MySQL with --skip-grant-tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables)

Comment: Editing my question, I tried that but go into an infinite loop of: "
2017-11-28  0:19:25 140737214337984 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2017-11-28  0:19:25 140737214337984 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files

Comment: What does SHOW GRANTS look like?

Comment: +--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple databases using the same innodb files; do a ps auwxf | grep -i sql after you stop the server. If nothing is shown then do a lsof | grep ibdata and see if anything is using those files

Comment: Note: I am on Linux so OSX may vary in implementation

Comment: At which point you should just dump your dbs run docker and docker pull mariadb and call it a day :)

Comment: `ps auwx | grep -i sql` I get: Carvalho          4993   0.0  0.9  2932892  76660   ??  S    12:17AM   0:00.59 mysqld --skip-grant-tables
Carvalho          5152   0.0  0.0  2442612    552 s000  R+   12:28AM   0:00.00 grep -i sql

Comment: So probably the best thing would be to just try to uninstall and install again, right? I suppose I could use Homebrew installation instead of a Docker container? (never used Docker before)

Comment: Docker would be way easier; same with homebrew

Answer (score 0):

But you could kill -15 that sql process then restart with skip grants

Totally meant to make this a comment - sorry

Comment: I guess I just deleted everything using this link (https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d)... I'll restart my pc and see how Docker works.... thanks a lot!

Comment: just for reference, reinstalled using brew, and it turned out that a table called MySQL appeared... I'm guessing that was what was causing my privileges problems. Just can't figure out how it was deleted. anyway, is working, thanks a lot!