# Resetting MySQL root password giving error when running init-file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I know there are countless questions and posts about this, but I'm getting an error when trying to start the MySQL Server and I don't know how to solve it.

So to explain I cannot access my database so I tried to reset the password of the root user. I've followed [this guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) however I've had no luck. First I had issues with permissions on my machine and now I'm getting this error:

`1105  Bootstrap file error, return code (0). Nearest query: ''`

Technically the MySQL Server is starting, however the `init-file` is not being run, and so my password is not being reset.

**Command I am running is this:**

`mysqld --defaults-file="C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\my.ini" --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt --console`

**Contents of mysql-init.txt**

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';`

**The following is the part of the log where the error is shown:**

`[Note] Execution of init_file 'C:\\mysql-init.txt' started.
[ERROR] 1105  Bootstrap file error, return code (0). Nearest query: ''
[Note] Execution of init_file 'C:\\mysql-init.txt' ended.
[Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.`

**MySQL Version:** 5.7

**OS:** Windows 10

Comment: I managed to get around this issue by adding --skip-grant-tables in my.ini file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013868/2312637). That allowed me to log into MySQL through command line without a password. I than ran flush privileges and reset the password.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can pass the command:

```
--init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

as a parameter to start the MySQL service from its general tab.

([Source](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60965))

Answer (score 1):

Had two errors with MySQL 5.7.24

1.) The script file must be in a separate folder (not mysql installation folder or data directory)
and that folder must get "secure-file-privileges"

2.) The error above was raised for the script did not end with a ';'

Succeeded then with command line statement as

```
mysqld --datadir=D:\ProgramData\mysql\data --init-file=D:\ProgramData\mysql\reset\reset.sql --secure-file-priv=D:\ProgramData\mysql\reset --console
```

and SQL-script file 'reset.sql' as

```
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'root_pwd';
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, on Ubuntu, problem was init file was not owned by `mysql` user.

```
chown mysql:mysql /tmp/reset_mysql_pswd.sql
sudo mysqld --init-file=/var/lib/mysql/reset_mysql_pswd.sql
# ^C or kill -9 <mysqld pid>
systemctl stop mysql.service
systemctl start mysql.service
```

---

Even when the folder containing the init file and the init file itself had permissions `777` (which is a bad idea), I still get:

```
2020-04-10T23:14:48.030719Z 0 [Note] Execution of init_file '/tmp/reset_mysql_pswd.sql' started.
2020-04-10T23:14:48.030764Z 0 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/tmp/reset_mysql_pswd.sql' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2020-04-10T23:14:48.030772Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: I had a problem that mysqld refused to read the init-file  (Errcode 13), regardless of its owner:group and regardless of its permissions. Very strange! It only worked when I placed it in /etc/mysql. My guess is that mysqld is picky about where it reads files.