# Plugin 'my_root_password' is not loaded

Tags: mysql, whm

I read a stack article that said to run the following, to be able to connect to MySQL root from remote HeidiSQL client:

```
update user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where User='root';
```

I think I misinterpreted it and ran:

```
update user set plugin='my_actual_mysql_root_password' where User='root';
```

I'm thinking I was supposed to take `"mysql_native_password"` LITERALLY!??

Because after running my update, it executed, and now I can no longer connect to MySQL via terminal inside WHM. When I run the following inside terminal (which used to work)...

```
sudo -i mysql
```

It won't connect to MySQL, and I get this error:

> Plugin 'my_actual_mysql_root_password' is not loaded.

The fact that the error message spits back my *ACTUAL ROOT MYSQL PASSWORD* tells me I've done something wrong. I can no longer access MySQL from command line.

Comment: Have you tried running the MySQL server with [`--skip-grant-tables`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables) and fixing the entries then?

Comment: Progman, how do I run that from inside WHM terminal? Can you give me exact syntax? And then...how do I fix the entries?

Comment: Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables/35277160#35277160, it has a step-by-step instruction on how to fix the root user access.