# unable to access mysql database from python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I tried to access data from mysql database through python then I tried as

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1",
                     port = 3306,
                      user="Bishnu",
                      password = "Pulchowk",
                      db = "telecom_db")
cursor =db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from profile")
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
for x in range(numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    #if (row):
    print row[0], row[1]

cursor.close()

db.cose()
```

then it shows error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Bishnu\BE\4th year\7th semester\Major Project I\Workspace\Bishnuji\default\first.py", line 43, in <module>
    db = "telecom_db")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: 'password' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Then I also tried removing password as

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1",
                     port = 3306,
                      user="Bishnu",
                      #password = "Pulchowk",
                      db = "telecom_db")
cursor =db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from profile")
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
for x in range(numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    #if (row):
    print row[0], row[1]

cursor.close()

db.cose()
```

still it shows error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Bishnu\BE\4th year\7th semester\Major Project I\Workspace\Bishnuji\default\first.py", line 43, in <module>
    db = "telecom_db")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'telecom_db'")
```

What may be the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether you have set password on your database or not. Normally user name and password are not changed and Default user name = 'root' and password filled is null i.e password = ''. If you have set password and forgot it then you can retrieve it by following instruction stated at [How do I retrieve my MySQL username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371/how-do-i-retrieve-my-mysql-username-and-password)

Answer (score 11):

from the [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) seems that the correct naming of the parameter is `passwd`

Comment: I changed my password to passwd still there is the second type error that is _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'telecom_db'")

Comment: Is it normal that the username is missing from the error message? BTW, are you sure that the password is right? are you able to connect from the command line with the same parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Please uninstall and again install the mysqlclient using commands
for uninstall

```
pip uninstall mysqlclient
```

for install

```
pip install mysqlclient
```