# Getting password from CPANEL using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, password-recovery

Good Day

I am a front-end developer, and I know little from MySQL and databases.

I have a Wordpress MySQL database in CPanel. Now I forgot my password, and the password for my user as seen in phpmyadmin  is hashed/encrypted.

How do I get the password?

NOTE: I do not have access to the Server since this is a website on a shared hosting account, so doing the following is not possible for me:

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371/how-do-i-retrieve-my-mysql-username-and-password) post on Stack

> Stop the MySQL process.
>
> Start the MySQL process with the --skip-grant-tables option.
>
> Start the MySQL console client with the -u root option.

List all the users;

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

Reset password;

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('[password]') WHERE User='[username]';
```

---

But **DO NOT FORGET** to

> Stop the MySQL process
>
> Start the MySQL Process normally (i.e. without the --skip-grant-tables option)

when you are finished.  Otherwise, your database's security could be compromised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your website is working you can probably find the mysql user/password
in the `config.php` file in your wordpress filesystem.

**Otherwise:**

Your best option is probably to add a user to the database and give it the needed privileges, to do that:

1. Click MySQL databases.
2. Create new user.
3. Assign new user to your database.
4. Edit `config.php` on your wordpress filesystem and change to the new username.

This is sub optimal, but will work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way for you to gain access to your WordPress user info if you don't know the password. I'm assuming you are talking about a WordPress user password retrieval. You need to have access and edit privileges to your database to do this.

-Open up phpMyAdmin or however you prefer to access database tables

-Select your database

-Open the table **wp_users**

-Under the column 'user_login' you will need to find which entry you want to access. Your username should be in one of the row entries.

-Once found, there will be a '**user_pass**' column as well. Now some explaining needs to happen. You cannot retrieve your password without hacking/brute forcing that encryption. These are MD5 hash encrypted passwords. What we are going to do is just simply create a new password here. All you have to do is Google "MD5 Hash generator". I tested this on the first result I found and it worked.

-Once you find a website with a generator just simply type in your password and then retrieve the hash that's given to you. For example I typed in 'password' and I receive '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99' Now we have a new encrypted password to set. If you are worried about sites saving your password entries or hashes just make up a password as a temporary fix. Then you can just login with that and change the password via the WordPress Dashboard later.

-Select the row that your username is in. Click Change/Edit then just copy and paste the entire MD5 Hash into the **wp_pass** column.(Overwrite the old password btw.) Save/Go/Execute to make sure the table was re-written. In this example I would be pasting '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99' into the column without quotes of course.

-Please be sure to only change the 'wp_pass' entry and to make sure it's corresponding to the correct username.(On the same row)

-Now you should be able to login with your new password.('password')