# Forgotten MySQL username on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu-12.04, gnome-terminal

I've forgotten my MySQL owner details.
I need a way to find my username.
My password will not be a problem.
I use Ubuntu 12.04 Linux, and would prefer a command line solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you log in with any other username?

Comment: MySQL's owner is usually `mysql`

Comment: Question is duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371/how-do-i-retrieve-my-mysql-username-and-password

Comment: Its not duplicate. I saw that when I googled 16 mins ago. That works for windows not debian linux. Got it?

Answer (score 7):

Well, then you have a clear way to restore it:

1. Run your MySQL server with [skipping grant tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) option.
2. Log in as root
3. Run query

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT user FROM mysql.user
   ```
4. That's it - you have a list of users. Save it somewhere, then run server normally and try your user names one by one.

Tip: if you want to reset root password, there's a corresponding [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Comment: Let me check this. I'll get back. Thanks.

Comment: Pls, how do I run with skipping grant tables option. I didn't find anything readable code in the docs link.

Comment: @EmmanuelHarrison see [this sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Well there is simple way how to change mysql user password as root

```
mysql -u root -p password
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR username = PASSWORD('new_password_here');
```

Comment: I got this error: "ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
".

Comment: it asks for password and says unknown database password