# how can I recover phpmyadmin password

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I did something wrong with the users of the phpmyadmin user and now i cannot access phpmyadmin with the old password. can someone help please?

The error is as follows:

## 1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Can i recover the password or reset the settings?

I have tried these instructions
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

error:

```
   * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                         [fail]
```

Comment: seek your systems administer with their favourite burger :)

Comment: Will deliver that to you dude. just guide me. the prob is, its my localhost and I am the admin myself:P

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve my MySQL username and password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371/how-do-i-retrieve-my-mysql-username-and-password)

Comment: Also see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: i want to completely remove and then reinstall phpmyadmin and mysql. will it work?

Comment: @user3526694 I guess you're going to have to ask yourself? :O I've never done it before but I'm sure there's an option to do so. Google it.

Comment: wao... thanks Beneto:)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reset the password on MySQL server as PMA is using them for login.

Comment: I am using ubuntu. can u guide me how do i do that?