# MySQL - Restrict access to a database

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to restrict users from accessing a particular database/schema within MySQL?

I want to create a database/schema that only I can access.

I also want to change the password of the "mysql" user but I do not see this user in the mysql.user table even though I was able to use this user to login to mysql.
I tried changing the password of the user by executing the statement - 
    `mysqladmin --user=mysql --password=oldpassword password "newpassword"`.
But now I am not able to login this user altogether. I've tried both the old and the new passwords.
I am wondering if my changing this password can impact any mysql service running on the system.

Comment: you must establish user permissions in the database, to give access to certain things that the administrator decides.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Answer (score 1):

For restricting table and schema you can use the GRANT, you can set permission for each user or group on a particular tables for more details :
[Tutorial on Grant for mysql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql)

For your access the answer is already on stackoverflow :[How do I retrieve my MySQL username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371/how-do-i-retrieve-my-mysql-username-and-password)

Hope that can help you

Comment: Thanks! .. But I don't see this user in mysql.user table. The username is "mysql". I guess this user is the owner of the whole mysql functionality.