# Where is the default root password for MySQL on Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

After a fresh new install of MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 19, when I attempt to log in for first time I cannot because I don't have the credentials. But the install did not prompt for credentials. I tried doing a grep for 'temporary password' in the following directories but none have a temp password. Where is the default password located? Thank you.

```
/var/log/mysql/error.log
```

and

```
/var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Did you try with an empty one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve my MySQL username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371/how-do-i-retrieve-my-mysql-username-and-password)

Comment: I tried blank. Did not work. Requires a password.

Answer (score 3):

Restart MySQL in passwordless mode, reset the password, restart the MySQL service.

```
# 1 : Stop mysql service
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
# 2: Start to MySQL server w/o password:
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
# Step # 3: Connect to mysql server using mysql client:
mysql -u root
```

```sql
-- 4: Setup new MySQL root user password
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
flush privileges;
quit
```

```
# 5: Stop MySQL Server:
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
# 6: Start MySQL server and test it
/etc/init.d/mysql start
mysql -u root -p
```

[source](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html)

[from search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=recover%20mysql%20root%20password&atb=v110-1&ia=web)

Comment: After doing step 2, attempting step 3 doesn't work. I get 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket'  error.

Comment: I also get the following when attempting step 2. ' mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.'

Comment: What is the output of `ps aux | grep mysql`

Comment: Can do you a reinstall of mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
Follow these step to resolve this

Find your socket file by running.

sudo find / -type s

create a link to this file in tmp directory.

sudo ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: by default, for root user there's no password.

Answer (score 1):

Well, none of the above well-intentioned answers worked for me, on Ubuntu 20.04-6.  Turns out, mysqld's default socket file path doesn't exist when mysqld isn't running, and mysqld_safe doesn't create it.  So the answer is to create the socket directory, and also set ownership to Unix user mysql-

```bash
$ sudo systemctl stop mysql.service
$ sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
$ sudo chown mysql.mysql /var/run/mysqld
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock &
$ mysql -u root
> *proceed with mysql password change*
> ^D
$ mysqladmin shutdown
$ sudo systemctl start mysql.service
```

This worked for me.  Now you should be able to go about your mysql business as usual, as I was.

UPDATE- if you've just installed MySQL 8.0+, there's now a straightforward way to set the root password: [Securing the Initial MySQL Account](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html)