# Could not drop database `symfony-project` for connection named default An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, doctrine

I accidentally created a database `symfony-project` successfully, but it's not appearing on my phpmyadmin page. I want to drop the database with

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force
```

then this message comes out

> Could not drop database `symfony-project` for connection named default
>   An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

When I try to create a new database, with `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`, an error message comes out:

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:
>    An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 31:
>    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 27:
>    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Because the connection is refused, I can't create and drop any databases right now.

My database url on the .env file is

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony-project?serverVersion=5.7
```

My password is empty.

I've tried to change the `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` and the error message is telling me that

> there is no such file or directory.

I'm using symfony 4 and xampp on macOS

### UPDATE

I've edited my config/packages/doctrine.yaml file. I commented the `url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'` and added this:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    dbname: symfony-project
    charset: utf8
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 8080
    user: root
    password:
    driver: pdo_mysql
```

and now this message comes out

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 106:
>    An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 31:
>    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 27:
>    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 27:
>    PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure the database really exists? Maybe that's why the connection is refused and why it's not shown in phpmyadmin. Have you tried connecting to mysql from the command line and run a query like `SHOW DATABASES;`

Comment: I’ve tried to connect to mysql and it turns out to show the message above. Previously, I have successfully connect to mysql and create the database. I’m sure the database is exist because when I create the database with doctrine:database:create, it shows that the database is created succesfully. But when I check the phpmyadmin page, the database is not there.

Comment: @dbrumann I've open mysql via phpmyadmin and run the code `SHOW DATABASES;`. The database `symfony-project` is not there.

Comment: Try password "null" (Don't use quotes)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also try the connection by attempt to create a database:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

If you're using Symfony 2, you need to use:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

I also see that in the string:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony-project?serverVersion=5.7
```

You didn't specify the password for `root` user. Although that might be not an issue if the password is unspecified at the beginning, it's better to re-check these credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried to create a new database and it's still showing the same message. Right now, I cannot create and drop any databases at all. By the way, I'm using Symfony 4 and my root user password is empty.

Comment: How do I check the password for my user? What I know is i don't have any password for my user. Sorry for my basic knowledge.

Comment: Whoops, just found that you actually can't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371/how-do-i-retrieve-my-mysql-username-and-password. But you can reset it according to the instructions following the answers in that question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your **doctrine.yaml**

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
      dbname:       database
      charset:      utf8
      user:         user
      password:     secret
      driver:       pdo_mysql
```

Check the documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Comment: The port of sql should be 3306, in your doctrine.yaml try to change your port to 3306

Answer (score 0):

The `php.ini` file might differ, so use this command on your project directory terminal:

`php --ini`

This command will give you the directions to your project `php.ini` file. In my case, it was `C:\Program Files\php-8.2.9-Win32-vs16-x64\php.ini`, in other cases it's located in the `xamp/php` folder.

Then locate or search for `extension=bz2` and `extension=pdo_mysql`. Make sure they are both uncommented.

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71RaW.png)

Make sure, you define your db variables in your `config/doctrine.yaml` like this:

```yaml
doctrine:
    #url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    dbal:
        dbname:       database
        charset:      utf8
        user:         user
        password:     secret
    driver:       pdo_mysql
```

Or you could also use your `.env` to define database link by uncommenting the url field in doctrine above and go to your `.env` file.

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://databaseusername:thisisdatabasepassword@127.0.0.1:3306/databasename?serverVersion=8.0.32&charset=utf8mb4"`
```

Make sure all parameters are correct, else you'll get access denied error from mysql. From here on all doctrine commands sould work fine.