# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost on mysql/mariadb

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, privileges

How can we solve this one ? anyone got an idea ? thank you , will be much appreaciated.

So in order to solve this one I did try to uninstall sql and mariadb

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y
$ sudo apt-get autoremove -y
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
```

And I install mariadb again

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

But when I run my node app using NPM RUN DEV I got the issue

[image]

when I run sudo systemctl status mariadb

[image]

Comment: your db password is wrong , check [How do I retrieve my MySQL username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371/how-do-i-retrieve-my-mysql-username-and-password) to retrieve your password

Comment: I see , let me try sir , be back

Comment: @anehme Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: How about to provide some more details like server version and operating system/distribution?!