# Check mysqls current users password

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, mysql-workbench

Is there any way with which I can view the password of mysql current user using query.

Comment: No, passwords are hashed. You should know the password though if you are connecting, it is one of the parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I retrieve my MySQL username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371/how-do-i-retrieve-my-mysql-username-and-password)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL passwords for users are stored within MySQL itself; they are stored in the mysql.user table. The passwords are hashed by default using the PASSWORD() function.
You cannot find the password from the hash.

Comment: Ok thanks, I got my answer